# How to set margin or padding in canvas object in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I need to draw something in the full browser window. However, I found it is sort of tricky to set it up with canvas object in D3.js. There is always a scrollbar on right side which was not there if I remove the js code.

Here is my code:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">    
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">

<div id="background" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; "> 
</div>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = document.getElementById("background").offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById("background").offsetHeight;
var canvas = d3.select("#background").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the code in , the orignial html will not have a scrollbar. So I suspect this might be related to the margin or padding of canvas object.

Could someone help?

Thanks
Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.canvas{
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
    display:block;
}
```

Give canvas an ID and set its display to 'block'. Seems to have sorted your problem :)

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4ukh5vjp/2/